# iOS/ Android - Can we implement a popup over an other popup?

Tags: usability, user-behavior, layout, ux-designer, lean-ux

When a user is prompted with a popup to select a option, Whether we can invoke a second popup over this first popup or closing/hiding the first popup to showcase the second one??

Or any other good suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple interconnecting popups is in itself not a very delightful experience, since it causes confusion. For example, can I as a user step back to the previous popup when the next popup appears if I believe that my action on the first popup was incorrect? What happens if I accept the terms stated in the first popup, but cancel in the second, is the action from the first popup dismissed or active?

Many questions can arise from this type of interaction pattern and it should be avoided. But it's still a matter of context, and what's possible to do.

For example when using a camera application and trying to take a photo the memory could be full. Then it could feel appropriate to display a popup explaining this and providing a set of actions, where one could be severe ("Delete old photos") and could motivate for an additional popup ("Are you sure?").
But these cases are quite rare in general terms.

A possible alternative approach can be to provide alternatives in the first popup (radio buttons for example) which triggers the actions of the second popup in the existing popup.

**So maybe rather than doing this:**

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZpGhH.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

**You could see if your case could be transferred into something like this:**

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMQejW.png)</sup>